# PInterest showing error "Sorry images can't be fetched"

Tags: php, .htaccess, pinterest

I was trying to pin images from my site, but some images from a page are fetched but some are not?
What could be the possible reason, i have deleted the robots.txt file as well, and .htaccess file is also ok, then what may be the possible reason for not fetching images.

sample url is http://style.merrykaufer.com/women/curated-outfit-34

Comment: I see "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuth "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain)

Comment: Also see [Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255315/cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains)