# Facebook App - The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. Why?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When trying to login with a Facebook app, I'm getting the following error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

As you can see on the following image:

[image]

URL: http://www.facebook-php-test.com

Below is the configuration I have set on my Facebook App.

(**Notice:** for privacy purposes I changed the values for `App ID` and `App Secret` on the image)

[image]

The code for this basic sample application is on this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/zeuscronos/facebook-php-test.com

I really don't know why it says that `the domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains` when it is actually there.

On the field: `App Domains` I tried with both domains at the same time:

- facebook-php-test.com
- www.facebook-php-test.com

but no success.

The generated login URL is as follows:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?client_id=012345678901234&state=d3758e484d539bebd6505427aaf1fa3b&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook-php-test.com%2Ffb-callback.php&scope=email%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_photos

I configured the domain: `facebook-php-test.com` as a virtual host on an Apache server.

I have to say that I have worked a lot with the `Facebook PHP SDK` and this is the first time I'm getting struggle with this.  Actually, I got this problem with another big application I was working with then after couple of hours trying to solve the problem I created this dummy application to try to figure out what's the cause of the problem.

I have tried many things with no success.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.

> #### EDIT 01

Following the suggestion of `Mr.Geeker` comment I did the following...

Added the product: `Facebook Login` and configured like below:

[image]

Then, finally I could go forward, and I was asked for permissions:

[image]

But unfortunately, after granting permissions, I got the following:

[image]

Any idea on how to continue from this point?

> #### EDIT 02 - SOLUTION

I ended disabling the option: `Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs` under `Client OAuth Settings`. They say it is `strongly recommended` has this feature `On` but I could not get this working with that `On`.

By the way I also disabled: `Client OAuth Login` since my app doesn't use it.

Finally, the only feature I have enable under: `Client OAuth Settings` is: `Web OAuth Login`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255315/cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Facebook now roles some features as plugins. In the left hand side select Products and add product. Then select Facbook Login. Pretty straight forward from there, you'll see all the Oauth options show up.

As originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255315/cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains/37504496#37504496)

Comment: thanks, I could move forward but continue with errors, please, see my post edition. One question, is this something new?, I have other Facebook applications configured without that `product` and they are working properly.

Comment: your settings seems good , double check your Site URL remove `/` from the end , and also double check your `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` if it's correct , and im still trying to understand why it's not working with you

Comment: When I remove the `/` from the end of the `Site URL` on my first image and then click `Save`, that `/` appears again. I double checked the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` and that's the callback URL I have set up on my application. Any other idea?, Thanks!

Comment: `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` = `http://www.facebook-php-test.com/fb-callback.php` which is correct. You can check my image above. Also, you have the source code on the linked GitHub repository above.

Comment: This is now solved. For more info, take a look at my `Edit 02`.

Comment: The error message is still odd. It clearly states _The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains_ - but it is! I am experiencing the same thing. Furthermore, _Valid OAuth redirect URIs_ should **not** be necessary, according to the description, if you enabled _Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs_ (which is enabled by default) **and use the Facebook SDK** - which I am and you (Angel) are too. I do not want to define a _Valid OAuth redirect URI_, since it can be dynamic in my case. This is a frustrating error. This seems more like a bug from Facebook to me.

Answer (score 4):

On March 2018, facebook updated the API and forced all apps to keep strict mode On.

To make it work, you have to include the full callback url in the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field. If you redirect to "https://www.example.com/facebook/callback", the full URI must be included (without parameters):

[image]

The domain must be set in the App domains and the Website Site URL fields on the basic settings page:

[image]

If none of these works and the "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains." message keeps showing, **check if you have the latest version of the SDK**. I could make it work after updating de PHP SDK from version 5.5 to 5.6.2

Comment: Thank for sharing a latest updated by facebook. It will be helpful for many

Comment: This one worked for me, thank you very much for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PHP 5.5 and I found the bug.

The PHP Facebook API VERSION = '5.5.0', DEFAULT_GRAPH_VERSION = 'v2.9' was adding the URI **?code=XXX** in my callback page like this:

mydomainExample.com/callbackFacebook.php **?code=XXXXXXX**

and I changed the source code to remove the string after '?'. Now the callback url is only

mydomainExample.com/callbackFacebook.php

The fixed can be done in the file Facebook/Helpers/ **FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php** inside the **getAccessToken** function. I added a '**if**' as below in the line 226 and the issue gone:

```
$redirectUrl = $redirectUrl ?: $this->urlDetectionHandler->getCurrentUrl();

//the next 3 lines was added to avoid the bug (fixed)
if(strripos($redirectUrl, "?")){
  $redirectUrl = substr($redirectUrl, 0, strripos($redirectUrl, "?"));
}

// At minimum we need to remove the state param
$redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state']);
```