# The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. (subdomains!)

Tags: php, facebook

my question is the same as this:

> [Facebook App - The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762646/facebook-app-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains-why)

except that my url is: `http://ccc.nnn.hhh.hu`

The settins on fb, "facebook login":

Client OAuth Login: ON

Web OAuth Login: ON

Valid OAuth Redirect URIs: http://ccc.nnn.hhh.hu/my.php

strict mode is ON (cannot be disabled)

At basic:

App Domains: http://ccc.nnn.hhh.hu

so, when trying to login, the facebook dialogs asks for the username and password, so far so good. And then I get an exception for this:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => aeaeae,
    'app_secret' => rrrrr,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

and I wont get the $accessToken but the execption:

The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains.

Comment: The first thing `http://ccc.nnn.hhh.hu` does, is redirect me to `http://mywww.hu/` …?

Comment: its a fictional made up name.....................

Comment: Well isn’t that clever ... good luck then. (At this level of dipsh*tdity regarding providing relevant info, I’m out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you have to upgrade the sdk to "5.6.2" to support `strict mode`.

Facebook is forcing strict mode by default now, and that implies that we should use a standard redirect URL, or declare our old custom URI in the `Valid Oauth redirect URIs` list. See:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/

So, apart from upgrading the sdk, you guys want to add your custom URI in the list to support legacy app flows.

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved.

I was using "5.4.2" and upgraded to "5.6.2".