# Facebook API Error Loading

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Getting this error while Facebook Api creation:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Comment: Learn how to format your questions appropriately.

Comment: Please help..dnt downvote,,as a developer i have been trouble.

Comment: Please format your question properly, if you look at this, could you answer it? Because we certainly can't.

Comment: Give some more details, screenshots etc for better understanding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255315/cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains)

Comment: I have edited your question to the best of my ability. I think you should add more details to prevent downvoting and more importantly, to get a useful answer.

Comment: You should definitely add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _“Please help..dnt downvote,,as a developer i have been trouble.”_ - as you _should be_, if you really think asking like above was worthy of a “developer” even remotely. This particular error message has been discussed numerous times over the last few weeks, and the documentation also explicitly explains what settings you need to make. Your question does not even sound like you did _any_ research upfront.

Comment: Hi John, there is currently an issue connecting to FB groups via API. If that is where you are seeing this error then you can't do much. This is from FB's end.

Answer (score 0):

Set your app details by whitelisting websites/web-API, capable of accessing the Graph API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#app-settings