# facebook login in xamarin forms

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, facebook-login

I am using the https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms for Facebook login.

I am doing the settings in developers.facebook.com for android and added the  Hashkey,Class name and added the Google Play Package Name as the Package Name in Android Manifest but shown invalid. I got the error below:

`Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings`

How to solve this error? What could be the actual Google Play Package Name for Xamarin Android?.Need some Help...

Comment: Add your c# code please.

Comment: Maybe this error has been raised.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255315/cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains).You can show some code where may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the redirect URL under facebook dev portal? This is required to complete the authentication flow as per facebook guidelines. You can find more details about it here:

https://timothelariviere.com/2017/10/11/authenticate-users-through-facebook-using-xamarin-auth/